# What are Processes in Cpanel?

Tags: node.js, cpanel, web-hosting

[Number of processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPk6B.png)

My Cpanel have a limit of 50 processes.
If I exceed this limit my website crashed. I am using mainly Nodejs for my site.
I want to know what are these processes and how can I increase their limit and/or reduce total number of processes. Is it a web hosting problem or coding problem?

Answer (score 0):

The second result in Google pulled the below result. To increase them, it seems you need upgrade your plan.

https://my.wirenine.com/knowledgebase/4259/What-are-Entry-Processes-in-cPanel.html

> When you log into cPanel you will notice "Entry processes" on the
> sidebar with a number. This is the number of connections your account
> can process simultaneously. Your entry processes limit will vary by
> plan.
>
> Please note, the number of simultaneous connections is not the same as
> the number of visitors you can have on your website at one time.  That
> means a limit of 30 entry processes does equal to 30 people visiting
> your website. Connections are only counted while they process, as soon
> as the process is complete it is no longer counted as an active
> process. For example, if your website has a visitor and it takes 1
> second to load while generating only a single HTTP connection, that
> visitor will count as a single process. Although they will continue to
> view your website, they will no longer be counted as an active process
> until they do something else to create a new process such as
> navigating to a new page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am not asking about "Entry Process"(EP). I want to know about "Number of processes"(NPROC). I wants to know what processes are still running and causing NPROC to reach its limit.

Comment: @Nikhil you can get an idea by running `ps aux` on terminal (In cPanel).